# Could we use Singleton Design Pattern without static method?

Tags: c#

What is the use of a singleton design pattern.net application? Could we implement without a private and Protected Constructor? Why need a static method?

Could we use Singleton Design Pattern without static method?

Comment: "Why need a static method?" -- Because a non-static method would need an instance object to be called from. Since the point of the singleton pattern is to have only one instance of the object, ever, how would you get that one object if not through something static?

Comment: Do it with your DI container. (However, your DI container should be a singleton.)

Comment: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton#lazy

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: What are you really asking? You can use DI, you can use `Lazy<T>`. The `static` property (not method) in C# ensures deterministic and thread-safe initialization. The private constructor ensures only one instance can be created.

Comment: is this just a question of reasoning about the pattern or do you have a specific issue with a private constructor and a static method?

Comment: I suppose you could create a factory object, which reads from a static field, but what would be the point?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Using Singleton design pattern, you want to ensure that there is only one instance of your object. If you have any other publicly accessible methods to create another instance, then you can not ensure that.
The only way is to use a class method, or a static factory method, which ensure that only one object is created and returned.